# How do I change eslint styling organization from alphabetical?

Tags: react-native, eslint, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

I am using eslint to organize my styling code, but was wondering if there are different options other than alphabetical styling ordering. Currently eslint suggests I change this:

```
Tag: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 19,
    marginBottom: 1,
    marginLeft: 2,
},
```

To this:

```
Tag: {
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    height: 19,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginBottom: 1,
    marginLeft: 2,
},
```

While this does follow a consistent pattern for all of the styling in my code, this organization doesn't seem the most helpful for quickly understanding what Tag does. I personally tend to group all of my flexbox styling together whereas organizing alphabetically separates these stylings.

Is there a way to setup eslint to suggest different styling organization than alphabetical?

Comment: Apply eslint rule ```react-native/sort-styles``` (https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native/blob/master/docs/rules/sort-styles.md).

Comment: Is there a way to organize the styling into groups with eslint rather than asc vs. desc order?

Comment: I don't know. What kind of groups do you mean?

Comment: I might be looking for something which doesn't exist, but grouping spacing styling, flexbox styling, background image styling, font styling as different groups is handy and easier to read.

Comment: AFAIK such a sorting does not exists.

Comment: dang it, no worries thanks